# IIS Proxy/pass through question

Tags: iis, proxy, passthru

We have set of computers that need to access a certain web application (MVC) hosted on our ASP.NET box. These computers are on their own little subnet that can only see a small back office server that controls them.

That server, in turn, can see the entire rest of our network including the ASP.NET box in questions.

What I need to figure out is how to use IIS on the middle server to send requests to and from the ASP.NET box to these computers. I'm not sure if I need a proxy or if there is a way to do this soley through IIS. Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a rather old question, but I thought worth answering. IIS is not necessarily the best technology of choice here as it is intended to provide a service, not so much to relay a service.

However, if you really wanted to use IIS you can install a product like [Helicon Tech's ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) which supports the proxying of websites through IIS with very little configuration. However, this will be using valuable resources on your server for a problem that may not merit it.

Given my understanding that you own both networks (the parent network and the child "secure" network) and that they are both on different subnets but internal, you should be able to use a standard router from your favorite computer supply store to act as the bridge. The router can be told to allow access to a specific port/IP combo on the secure network but no others. This configuration will vary from router to router, but the concept is the same. On a more capable router like a Cisco ASA5505 you can very easily bridge accross multiple child subnets on different physical ports (with any combination of permissions/restrictions) while maintaining the same public interface for internet access. Having a dedicated router like this will provide much greater performance and reliability than proxying through a shared server and IMO better security control.

Bottom line is that you have multiple options for solving your problem, but my personal preference would be to adjust the network architecture/router to accomodate your needs before I would use IIS as a proxy server.